# Can nonconserved energy in GR be thought of as going into gravitational field energy?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

One of the most striking features of GR is that energy is not conserved. Carroll's GR text has an interesting statement about this:

> Clearly, in an expanding universe [...] the background is changing with time; therefore there is no reason to believe that the energy should be conserved. [...] The transition from flat to curved spacetime induces the additional Christoffel-symbol terms in $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$; these terms serve, roughly speaking, to allow transfer of energy between the matter fields (comprising $T^{\mu\nu}$) and the gravitational field.

The book says nothing more, but it seems to imply that when energy is not conserved in GR, it goes into gravitational energy. But I'm not sure how to define such a thing in GR.

- Is there a way to define gravitational potential/field energy in GR?
- Is the sum of this quantity and $T^{\mu\nu}$ conserved?

Comment: Transfer of energy into the gravitational field alone would hardly count as energy-non-conservation. It's pretty much the same mistake (in judgement) one makes in classical electrodynamics when neglecting radiation of charges. Now, there is the question of what happens to the energy of radiation that gets redshifted on an expanding background and the answer is simple: we don't know and it's not clear if the usual assumption that expanding background is non-conserving because of Noether's theorem is the correct approach.

Comment: The "Physics FAQ" goes into considerable detail; see http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html

Comment: The Stress-Energy tensor is about energy and momentum *density* it doesn't even have units of Joules, it has units of Joules per cubic meter. And there isn't a frame invariant way to break it into energy density and momentum density. And even if you had an energy density scalar field at every event there still isn't a frame invariant way to turn an energy density field into an overall energy because of a lack of simultaneity. So energy isn't a thing. But that's fine, you can make predictions anyway. The predictions can be compared to observations. So you can do science. That's what's important

Comment: So, judging from the comments, the answer is no, it was just a random remark?

Comment: @Peter Diehr That's a great article, and highlights what an interesting area this is. I remember reading somewhere that gravitational potential may have an equal scale and opposite sign to mass, making the universes total energy zero. Which has intuitive appeal given conservation laws

Comment: @CriglCragl:  Energy is not conserved in GR; but it is conserved in Newtonian gravitation.  Perhaps what you read was an article about the latter.